# Read different size and format images to form a queue in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I meet a problem on for Tensorflow. I want to read some bmp and jpeg images to form the queue in Tensorflow. And these images have different size.

The input is image path list and label list. 
Currently I use " tf.train.slice_input_producer" (generate queue), "tf.image.decode_image" (read different format image), "tf.image.resize_images" (resize image to same size).

However, here I have some problems. The "tf.image.resize_images" needs image shape but there is no shape from "tf.image.decode_image". If I set fixed image shape manually, there will be error to read some images with different size.

Is there any better way for this issue (read different size and format images in Tensorflow)?

```
images = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_list)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_list)
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels]) #Slice_input producer shuffles the data by default.

#Decode 
image = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
image = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=3) # for different format
label = input_queue[1]

image.set_shape([640, 480, 3]) # if I dont set the shape, "tf.image.resize_images" cannot work, if I set it, it is fixed... 

image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [160, 120])
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image , label], batch_size=batch_size)

return image_batch, label_batch
```

Comment: Please show your code. The idea seems good, so there must be some bug in your code